# Implementing mmap's `MAP_POPULATE` flag in Windows and other Unices than Linux, and MADV_WILLNEED in Windows

Tags: c, linux, unix, winapi, memory-management

The implementation of Linux `mmap(2)` has an useful flag: `MAP_POPULATE`, which when specified, will prefault all pages we'are allocating.
Other Unices systems don't have this flag, except for FreeBSD which has a equivalent flag called `MAP_PREFAULT_READ`.

If I want to implement this behavior in Windows and other Unices systems how I could do that in the best way?

I thought 2 possible ways:

1) The most portable: just do a loop which writes a '\0' character at the base address of each allocated page (also the slowest implementation, if pages are many). Will this also have some bad implications that I'm not seeing right now?

2) Call `madvise()+MADV_WILLNEED` on Unices. Unfortunately an equivalent Windows version of this combination there isn't: on Windows you got only `VirtualAlloc()+MEM_RESET` which is the equivalent of `madvise()+MADV_DONTNEED` but you don't have a `madvise()+MADV_WILLNEED` to call, because even `VirtualAlloc()+MEM_RESET_UNDO` has to be called only *AFTER* `VirtualAlloc()+MEM_RESET` has been called on the same range of memory, otherwise the behavior is undefined.

So, there is space for another question: has Windows an equivalent of `madvise()+MADV_WILLNEED` to be used not only in this case, but in general, as a way to tell Windows "look, I'll need those pages"?

Any thoughts?

Comment: Bad implications with writing a `\0` to each page? Uhm, well, if destroying data is good, then no.

Comment: They're new pages just allocated, so you don't destroy any data

Comment: [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) can be used with a file backing store as well. Why not read the first address instead of writing to it?

Comment: Yeah, maybe reading a word-sized type from each page base address would be the best, it should still cause a soft-fault

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of Windows 8 you can call the [`PrefetchVirtualMemory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh780543%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. That's similar to `madvise() + MADV_WILLNEED`.

Comment: As MSDN says: <<The PrefetchVirtualMemory function allows applications to make efficient use of disk hardware by issuing large, concurrent I/Os where possible when the application provides a list of process address ranges that are going to be accessed. Even for a single address range (e.g. a file mapping), the PrefetchVirtualMemory function can provide performance improvements by issuing a single large I/O rather than the many smaller I/Os that would be issued via page faulting.>> It seems that this API is more involved in disk I/O, than prefaulting pages like `madvise()+MADV_WILLNEED`.

Comment: The fact that you can pass multiple different address ranges to the API, proves that its target is to make more efficient I/O, a sort of readv() but for memory pages. I don't know if calling this API for prefaulting pages would be ok...MSDN doesn't say anything about that. And, by the way, its a too new API, there are *A LOT* of Windows pre-8 out there.

Comment: @MarcoPagliaricci: I'm stumped. What do you hope *prefaulting* would do, that *PrefectVirtualMemory* wouldn't? Isn't your ultimate goal to have the memory paged in (from a file backing store in case of a file mapping)?

Comment: @IInspectable, well first of all this API is not available on a *LOT* of Windows out there, but besides that, it seems to have a slight different behavior of `madvise()+MADV_WILLNEED`: <<The PVM function is purely a performance optimization: prefetching is not necessary for accessing the target address ranges. The prefetched memory is not added to the target process' working set; it is cached in physical memory. When the prefetched address ranges are accessed by the target process, they will be added to the working set.>> but I want to add them to the working set immediately,not when accessed.

Comment: Said that, I think that using PVM would be the best way to emulate a `madvise()+MEM_WILLNEED` on Windows. I'll do some more tests, thanks.

Comment: @MarcoPagliaricci: Maybe you should explain exactly which aspects of `madvise()`/`MADV_WILLNEED` you are interested in replicating. You should [update your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32049240/edit) with this information.

Comment: Ok, I think this question can be signed as resolved, then. I'll start a new one with more specific requests in the future